# Haskell game server auth: cookie key generate&check

Tags: game, haskell, linux, server

[C++ code version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/199727/game-server-auth-cookie-key-generatecheck) (description copied from it)

`gameKeys id` is authentication function of an MMO game server. When someone wants to play with friends, he sends request to server, server calls `generateId`, then `gameKeys id` and returns it as JSON using `encodeJSON` to player via API. When a friend establishes connection, he sends the game id and his key, server calls `gameKeys id`, where `id` is user data, and then checks user's key.

Algorithm is:

- use current time and internal counter to generate id if it's not provided, or use provided id
- make fast crypto hash using Blake2 function of id and secret(Yes, I know about HMAC and using as key, but in this case it doesn't matter)
- split 64-bit hash to four 16-bit values, one hash for one user
- make JSON object from id and keys and return it

I want to make stable code: exploit-free, no memory leaks and high speed (for high load and DDOS prevention). I'm experimenting now, so the algorithm was first written in JavaScript, then in C++ and now in Haskell.

I think Haskell is best in writing stable code.

Please review the Haskell code; I think it can be improved (I'm new to Haskell). Code compiles and works same as JS and C++. Also please advise me, which programming language is better for this: JS, C++ , Haskell or Go?

Here's the Haskell code; install dependencies `cabal install blake2 hex split unix-time json` to run it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.IORef
import System.IO.Unsafe
import qualified Crypto.Hash.BLAKE2.BLAKE2b as Blake2
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as Char8
import Data.Hex
import Data.Char
import Data.List.Split
import Data.UnixTime
import Text.JSON.Generic

topsecret = "TOPSECRET"

dateCounter :: IORef Int
dateCounter = unsafePerformIO (newIORef 0)

hashBytes :: Char8.ByteString -> Char8.ByteString
hashBytes = Blake2.hash 64 mempty;
hashHex :: String -> String
hashHex =  (map toLower) . Char8.unpack . hex . hashBytes . Char8.pack;
makeKeys :: String -> [String]
makeKeys = (chunksOf 32) . hashHex;

data GameAuth = GameAuth
  { id :: Int
  , keys :: [String]
  } deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

gameKeys id = GameAuth id (makeKeys ((show id)++"|keys|"++topsecret))

generateId = do
  time <- getUnixTime
  counter <- readIORef dateCounter
  modifyIORef dateCounter addCounter
  return $ shiftTime time counter
shiftTime time counter  = (fromEnum (utSeconds time))*1000 + counter
addCounter c = (c+1) `mod` 1000



main = do
  id <- generateId
  putStrLn (encodeJSON (gameKeys id))
```

Here's the node.js version; it needs `blakejs` (run `npm i blakejs` to install it):

```js
const TOPSECRET = "TOPSECRET", blake = require("blakejs").blake2bHex;
let dateCounter = 0;

function gameKey(checkId){
  let id = checkId || (Date.now()/1000>>0)*1000+(dateCounter++%1000),
    keys = blake(`${id}|keys|${TOPSECRET}`).match(/.{32}/g);
  return {id, keys};
}
console.log(gameKey());
```

Answer (score 3):

As [`modifyIORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-IORef.html#v:modifyIORef) notes, use `modifyIORef'` for counters.

I would wrap the unsafe usage of `unsafePerformIO` into a safer interface.

```
withCounter :: (Int -> IO a) -> IO a
withCounter action = let counter = unsafePerformIO $ newIORef 0 in do
  i <- readIORef counter
  modifyIORef' counter (+1)
  action i

generateId = withCounter $ \date -> do
  time <- fromEnum . utSeconds <$> getUnixTime
  return $ time * 1000 + mod date 1000
```

The `||` logic doesn't seem to be in the Haskell code yet.

I wouldn't give a name to a private function used only once.

Many of your brackets are redundant. The `hint` tool can tell you this.

It seems you want to use some but not all of what you define in other code. The code that uses this could make a difference in the review.

[`Data.Unique`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Unique.html) may interest you for id generation if you do not actually care about your exact behavior.